# Click in iframe → Parent window scroll to position?

Tags: jquery, iframe, scroll, jquery-animate

On clicking anywhere in an iframe, I want my parent page to scroll to a postion which is below the bottom of that iframe. But no matter how big of number I put for the offset here, the parent only scrolls until the bottom of the iframe is lined up with the bottom of the viewport - no farther. How can I get it to scroll beyond that?

```
$('#iframe1').click(function () {
    $('html,body', window.parent.document).animate({
        scrollTop: '+=' + 700 + 'px'
    }, 'fast');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my tests the following works just find in all four browsers I've tested (Firefox, IE, Chrome and Safari):

**main page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Main Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <iframe src="iframe.html" style="width:400px; height:500px;"></iframe>
    <div style="width: 200px;">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer enim diam,
      pharetra at aliquam sed, luctus vel augue. Donec nec hendrerit velit. Sed
      fermentum volutpat libero a viverra. Mauris gravida cursus pulvinar. Morbi lorem
      nunc, pretium ut sollicitudin vel, facilisis ac ligula. Vestibulum imperdiet
      luctus augue, id euismod diam posuere ut. Suspendisse commodo ante nec dui
      suscipit ullamcorper porta justo consequat. Sed et eleifend erat. Duis ornare,
      nisi id hendrerit commodo, mauris metus dapibus arcu, ac tempor arcu justo sed
      arcu. Sed elementum ornare dolor, ac malesuada est vulputate non. Etiam nisl
      sapien, vestibulum ut blandit sed, suscipit vel erat. Sed elementum orci vitae
      magna vulputate consequat at ac lorem. Aenean libero risus, ornare sed posuere
      vitae, molestie vitae elit.
    </p>
    <p>
      Nullam nec lorem id turpis iaculis pretium. Pellentesque quam libero, pulvinar
      vitae viverra at, tincidunt vel dui. Mauris libero nibh, posuere eget aliquet
      eget, fermentum nec mi. Cras at venenatis ipsum. Fusce sed fermentum ante. Nam
      varius quam in lectus dignissim consequat. Cras semper, ligula eu ullamcorper
      pulvinar, orci quam vulputate lorem, vel dignissim lectus ipsum a justo. Etiam
      nibh nisi, tristique sit amet adipiscing in, volutpat non dolor. Etiam eros mi,
      consectetur sed adipiscing ut, egestas vel mauris. Pellentesque habitant morbi
      tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Donec lacus
      leo, feugiat ac lacinia ac, aliquam quis ante. In eleifend gravida lectus, vitae
      rhoncus erat sagittis quis. In in nibh at risus faucibus dignissim. 
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**iframe content:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  <title>iframe Page</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    /// wait till document ready
    $(function(){
      /// target the entire iframe page for a click
      $('body').click(function () {
          /// step back to the parent window and tell it to animate scroll
          $('html,body', window.parent.document).animate({
              scrollTop: '+=700px'
          }, 'fast');
      });
    })
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer enim diam,
    pharetra at aliquam sed, luctus vel augue. Donec nec hendrerit velit. Sed
    fermentum volutpat libero a viverra. Mauris gravida cursus pulvinar. Morbi lorem
    nunc, pretium ut sollicitudin vel, facilisis ac ligula. Vestibulum imperdiet
    luctus augue, id euismod diam posuere ut. Suspendisse commodo ante nec dui
    suscipit ullamcorper porta justo consequat. Sed et eleifend erat. Duis ornare,
    nisi id hendrerit commodo, mauris metus dapibus arcu, ac tempor arcu justo sed
    arcu. Sed elementum ornare dolor, ac malesuada est vulputate non. Etiam nisl
    sapien, vestibulum ut blandit sed, suscipit vel erat. Sed elementum orci vitae
    magna vulputate consequat at ac lorem. Aenean libero risus, ornare sed posuere
    vitae, molestie vitae elit.
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

With the above I don't get any problems, so I can only assume that there is something in your page's set-up that is causing the issue. I'm not sure how your code is working by placing a 'click' handler directly on the iframe itself *(this doesn't work in any of my tests)* so it may be you have another click function elsewhere that is being triggered and is not scrolling the page as much as you expect? Either that or it could be a float or position issue (with regard to your iframe), but if you say you can manually scroll to the right location then I doubt this would be a cause.

Comment: There is more to the page below the iframe. I can scroll beyond this, to the desired postion manually.

Comment: Without some code and markup added to your question, it is a bit difficult to tell what is going on I'm afraid.

Comment: actually, it could be because you are scrolling both html & body simultaneously? Whilst one or the other will work for different browsers it maybe causing something odd to occur.. What happens if you just use 'body'?

Comment: Seems to be working for me... any item I click on in the iframe (mainly images) I get scrolled to the bottom of the outer page (on Firefox/Windows 7). Certain areas of the iframe aren't clickable because nearly every element inside your iframe is positioned absolutely.. which means your body element collapses to a thin line across the top of the frame. To fix this you should be able to change `$('body').click(function () {` to `$('html').click(function () {` - however I'd recommend changing your layout so it doesn't rely so heavily on position absolute. I can't reproduce the scroll problem tho

Comment: I'd also recommend getting rid of the position absolute on your body tag (plus the height: 1000px) as these cause dual scrollbars to appear which will also confuse your scrolling. The reason for this is that some browsers handle their scrolling on the BODY tag, where as other browsers handle the scrolling on the HTML tag.. trying to modify the overflow or positioning of either of these elements always causes issues unfortunately. Oh, and it also seems you have a reference error in your js near `$("#step1img").fadeIn(700);step2text` it looks like `step2text` shouldn't be there.

Comment: Ok. I learned alot from your comment. I was viewing it in Chrome. But I see that it does work fine in my Safari... I changed body to HTML, thanks for that suggestion. But the reason everything in the iframe is absolute, is because when they were relative, my imgs were moving around weird when the window is resized, and not lining up. But absolute positioning prevents that somehow. Also, I know the body styles are funky, but that was the only way I could get the body's bg to scroll with the other content. So many issues... Thanks for your help on this question though.

Comment: Sure thing, no problem at all :)

Comment: I changed all the things you mentioned, including my JS references. I  don't know which one fixed it, but it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I've found is to modify your iframe html to include onload="window.parent.parent.scrollTo(0,0)" as in this example:

```
<iframe src="https://myiframe.com" width="100%" height="1500px" onload="window.parent.parent.scrollTo(0,0)" />
```